# Why @media query not working? I have tried everything I think. I am developing on angular 10 if that matters

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have been trying to use a media query to resize some letters when the device or width of the browser screen changes.

I have checked the syntax and I have added on my main HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport"content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> on my main HTML
```

The media query I am trying to implement is this one:

```
@media screen and(max-width:720px)and (max-device-width:720px){
      .clock{
          font-size: 0.5em;
      }
    }
```

If it matters I am developing on Angular 10 in a Mac and testing with Safari and Chrome on a Mac computer and iPhone XS.

app.component.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
      <!-- shrink-to-fit=no -->
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body class="mat-app-background">
    <div class="page">
        <h1>Clock</h1>
        <div  class="menu-container" >
            <button mat-raised-button class="clock type1">World Clock</button>
            <button mat-raised-button class="clock type2">Alarm</button>
            <button mat-raised-button class="clock type3">Stopwatch</button>
            <button mat-raised-button class="clock type4" (click)="myFunction('hello')">Timer</button>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <!-- <div class="box"> box</div> -->
          <app-timer>
          </app-timer>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>


<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.css

```
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla&family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap');


h1{
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 6em;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.page{
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f1eaea;
}

.menu-container{
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  border: 0px solid black;
  background-color: #f1eaea;
  flex-direction: row;

  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.clock{
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  line-height: 1.4;

  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  height: 80%;
  width: 10em;

  margin: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
}

.type1{
  background-color: #002642;

}

.type2{
  background-color: #840032;

}

.type3{
  background-color: #E59500;

}

.type4{
  background-color: #2A9D8F;
}

.content{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-top: 5vh;
  justify-content: center;
  height: calc(100vh - 265px);
 
}

.box{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
}


@media screen and(max-width:720px)and (max-device-width:720px){
  .clock{
      font-size: 0.5em;
  }
}
```

Global css style.css

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body{
  min-height:100%;
  height:100vh;
}


html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: You're missing a space before and after 'and'. After fixing, your query would look like :
```@media screen and (max-width:720px) and (max-device-width:720px){```

Comment: @ishandeveloper even after adding the spacing it keeps not working. I don't know if there is any problem with my HTML structure or something.

Comment: As @ishandeveloper said, you need spaces around ‘and.’ Why do you have the max-device width setting? If you have that, you have to use a phone to test the page. If you use `@media screen and (max-width:720px)`, then you can test it on your laptop or desktop.

Comment: @RichDeBourke it ended up working thanks!